# Converting Constructor C++

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

Hey guys i wrote this class...

```
struct TestStruct {
int a;
TestStruct(int pA) : a(pA){};
};

template <typename T> class ClassA {
public:
 ClassA() : mTestStruct(sizeof(T)) {}

 ClassA(T *ptr) : mTestStruct(sizeof(T)){};

 ClassA(T param) : mTestStruct(sizeof(T)){};

 ClassA(ClassA<T> &p){};

private:
 TestStruct mTestStruct;
 ClassA<T> &operator=(T *ptr) { return *this; };
};
```

and want to do something like this. (I think it's called a converting constructor.)

```
    ClassA<long> p = new long;
```

But i get this.
I compiled it with -std=c++14

```
no viable constructor copying variable of type 'ClassA<long>'
```

this one works by the way...

```
ClassA<long> p(new long)
```

Any ideas?

EDITED: okay this is the code that i used  to reproduce the error message.

Comment: That class definition is bogus. Please post real code.

Comment: [Can not reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/015c33c7ea806933)

Comment: No, don't post "real code". Post the [MCVE] you've been debugging with for the past few days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ClassA<long> p(new long);
```

calls for a **constructor of `ClassA`** that gets `long` as parameter (`T=long`).

```
ClassA<long> p = new long;
```

tries to use a **copy constructor from `long` to `ClassA`** to assign the new `long` into `p`, which of course does not exist and cannot be used therefore.

---

You need to create a copy constructor in `ClassA` that gets a `&long` as the copied variable, something like:

```
ClassA(const T &obj)
{
    // do what you want to happen in the copy constructor
}
```

Comment: About `this = ClassA(obj)`: `this` is a constant pointer, it cannot be assigned to.

Comment: But why `&long`. I am assigning a pointer to long not a long value